# Load navigation property from inherited class

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

I want to get all contact entities (including Person -> Employees)

```
Contact
|<- Person
|   |-> Employer
|
|<- Organization 
|   |-> Employees
```

Person and Organization inherits from Contact.

When i use FirstOrDefault my employees and my employer entity were not loaded.

```
public Contact GetContactById(int id)
{
    var contact = GetContacts().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    return contact;
}

private IQueryable<Contact> GetContacts()
{
    var contacts = _contextProvider.Context.Contacts
        .Include("Addresses");

    return contacts;
}
```

That's my current workaround:

```
public Contact GetContactById(int id)
{
    var contact = GetContacts().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (contact is Organization)
    {
        var organization = contact as Organization;
        _contextProvider.Context.Entry(organization).Collection(o => o.Employees).Load();
    }
    else if (contact is Person)
    {
        var person = contact as Person;
        _contextProvider.Context.Entry(person).Reference(o => o.Employer).Load();
    }
    return contact;
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: what's the inheritance strategy - TPH, TPT, TPC?

Comment: the inheritance stategy is TPT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test this but a possible nudge in the right direction could be

```
private IQueryable<Contact> GetContacts()
{
    var people = _contextProvider.Context.Contacts
        .OfType<Person>()
        .Include("Employer");

    var organizations = _contextProvider.Context.Contacts
        .OfType<Organization>()
        .Include("Employees");

    return people.Concat<Contact>(organizations);
}
```