# Navigation property inverse with multiple types inheriting from one type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

cf/ [Load navigation property from inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186803/load-navigation-property-from-inherited-class)

I have a `ContentItem` class with two child classes in TPT, `Post` and `Event`.

I would like users to be able to make `Comment`s on both child classes.

I have read from above that EF cannot handle inheritance of navigation properties, so I place `Comments` as a property in both `Post` and `Event`.

What do I use as the inverse in `Comment` for the inverse property?

I would like to make a property for `ContentItem` in my `Comment` so that on saving, the comment's `ContentItem` property is set to either the `Post` or `Event` in question.

However, it does not save the `ContentItem`'s ID when I set `comment.ContentItem = myPost` or `comment.ContentItem = myEvent`.

Is this a supported use of EF? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the models for the above entities ?

Comment: You can't have an inverse property because it is dichotomous. What you're doing here is called *polymorphic associations*. Maybe this helps you to find some hints on the web.