# Entity Framework Include for subclass navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

In Entity Framework, it's easy to include navigation properties with Include, like `efContext.MyObjects.Where(mo => mo.prop == "value").Include(mo => mo.nav)`.  My problem is that I have an application where there is inheritance and I would like to, for the subclasses that will be included in my query, also include some of their navigation properties (but not all entities will be of the subclass).  Is there a way to do this?

I attempted to use the string overload of Include, but doing this leads to an exception being thrown complaining that the base class does not declare such a navigation property.

Comment: Have you tried the .Include("PropertyName") syntax?

Comment: @Der_Meister Yeah, it complains that my base class declares no such property.  I could clear that up in the original post though.

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18187523/991267

Comment: @Der_Meister I had the same thought and tried that and while it compiles and runs without error it still seems to be querying each time it hits the navigation properties in question in a loop.

Comment: Basically, you can't do that without a projection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635152/entity-framework-eager-loading-of-subclass-related-objects